# Order of elements in $Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have this question:

> Let $x, n$ be integers with $n \geq 2$ and $n$ not dividing $x$.  Show that the order o($\bar{x}$) of $x \in Z_n$ is
>   $o(\bar{x})= \frac{n}{HCF(x, n)}$

I've been thinking about it for ages but I still don't get why. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: HCF stands for highest common factor? The standard name is "greatest common divisor" and has the code `\gcd`, which gives $\gcd(x,y)$.

Comment: Also, what does $\bar x$ denote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\gcd(x,n) \cdot \operatorname{lcm}(x,n)=nx$.

Comment: Slightly confused by this. I thought gcd (greatest common divisor) and hcf (highest common factor) were the same thing?

Comment: @Joe: I wanted to say $lcm$, thank you.

Comment: Okay, thanks I have got it now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Denote $\rm\:gcd(x,y)\:$ by $\rm\:(x,y),\:$ and $\rm\:lcm(x,y)\:$ by $\rm\:[x,y].\ $ Below are two proofs.

$(1)\ \  \begin{eqnarray}\rm kx\equiv 0\iff  n\mid kx \iff n\mid kx,kn\iff n\mid (kx,kn)=k\, (x,n)\iff n/(x,n)\mid k
\end{eqnarray}$

$(2)\ \ \begin{eqnarray}\rm kx\equiv 0\iff  n\mid kx \iff x,n\mid kx\iff [x,n]\mid kx \iff [x,n]/x\mid k\iff n/(x,n)\mid k\end{eqnarray}$

where the last $\iff$ employs the fundamental $\rm\:lcm * gcd\:$ law: $\rm\: [x,n](x,n)\, =\, xn$.